# Ruby nested for loop to populate array of arrays

Tags: ruby, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to teach myself Ruby via coding Conway's Game of Life.

One of my preliminary steps to learn how arrays work is to create an array of arrays of Cell objects defined as follows:

```
class Cell
  def initialize(status, xpos, ypos)
    @status = status
    @position = [xpos,ypos]
  end
end

contents = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))

for i in 0..contents.length-1
  for j in 0..9
    contents.at(i).insert(j, Cell.new("DEAD", i, j))
  end
end
```

I would expect that `<code>contents</code>` would be a size 10 array (which it is) where each of the inner arrays are also of size 10; however each of the inner arrays end up being size 110, why is that?

EDIT

So it seems my main issue was misunderstanding how insert works.  I've since changed my code to as follows:

```
class Cell
  def initialize(status, xpos, ypos)
    @status = status
    @position = [xpos,ypos]
  end

  def declare_state
    puts "Position is [" + @position[0].to_s + ", " + @position[1].to_s + "] and status is " + @status
  end
end

contents = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))

for i in 0..9
  for j in 0..9
    contents[i][j] = Cell.new("DEAD", i, j))
  end
end

contents.each {
  |subarray| subarray.each {
    |cell| cell.declare_status
  }
}
```

It looks like all the `@xpos` values for all my Cell objects is being set to 9, which is unexpected.

Comment: Use two spaces for indentation.

Comment: Why not simplify your code using smaller arrays then it may become apparent why this is happening.

Comment: Ah it seems I was misunderstanding how insert works.  However, I'm still not quite getting the result I want, I'll update the question to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
contents = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))
```

an array with 10 positions is created. What you may not realize is that each of those positions is filled with the same array.

I think you wanted

```
contents = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) }
```

Comment: That just answered the issue I was running into, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly relate, but one way to fix this that would be more idiomatic with ruby would be to use `each_with_index` instead of having nested for loops. It would look like this:

```
class Cell
    def initialize(status, xpos, ypos)
      @status = status
      @position = [xpos,ypos]
    end
end

contents = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))

contents.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |cell, cell_index|
    contents[row_index][cell_index] = Cell.new("DEAD", row_index, cell_index)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First is your use of `insert`, which is creating new elements in the sub-arrays rather than editing the values. Rather than `contents.at(i).insert(j, cell)` you could use `contents[i][j] = cell` where `cell` is your cell object.

The second issue is that your use of `contents = Array.new(10, Array.new(10))` is creating one array with 10 elements referring to the same **single** array reference. If you run the `object_id` to each sub-array, you will see they all refer to the same object. Updating one of the sub-arrays will appear to update all of them as a result.